# Understanding Vladimir Maz'ya's Problem 72 what is $|dy|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, analytic-continuation

In the article "[Seventy Five (Thousand) Unsolved Problems in Analysis and Partial Differential Equations](https://users.mai.liu.se/vlama82/pdf/Problems2018l_0312.pdf)" by Vladimir Maz’ya

Problem 72 on page 36 is given as follows:

Let $C$ be the unit circle let $u(x)$ be a function on the unit circle. Define the operator $A$ as follows

$$ A(u)(x) = \int_{C} \frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|} |dy| $$

The spectrum of A is described in [79, Section 12.2.2].
Then the principal cauchy problem:

$$  \frac{d}{dt} + A, t> 0 $$

Which is reminiscent of the modified zeta function

$$ f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-z \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n}} $$

Admits a meromorphic extension to the entire complex plane. Study the properties of this extension.

So I have a couple questions here.

1. What is $|dy|$? The only way I can try to make sense of this is that the sign of the integral should cancel out the sign of $dy$ for every point on the unit circle. I.E. this is the same as:

$$ A(u)(x) = \int_{y \in C} \frac{u(x)-u(y)}{y|x-y|}  $$

But if that was true the author would've just gone ahead and said that. So I think I don't understand what $|dy|$ is supposed to be.

2. The author makes a mention that this is "reminiscent of the modified zeta function" but not equal to. I assume this means the modified zeta function's meromorphic continuation is known? Is there a reference for this and or an explicit construction?

The Reference [79] from the article is:

Maz’ya, V., Nazarov, S., Plamenevskij, B.: Asymptotic Theory of Elliptic Baundary Value Problems in Singularly Perturbed Domains, vol. I.
Birkh¨auser, Basel (2000)

And I cannot get a hold of this article at this time.

### Some More Notes:

Using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft%7Cdz%5Cright%7C%24&p=1) I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30224/i-dont-understand-this-step-in-my-professors-boardwork?noredirect=1) question where again a line integral on the unit circle is occuring and the symbol $|dz|$ indicates the line element here. So perhaps we need not know what $|dy|$ means at all to make sense of this (just consider it as a line integral over $C$). To be honest I'm still dissatisfied since usually with line elements $dl$ it is usually possible to expand $dl = a(x)dy + b(y)dy$. In this particular case I'm still not sure how to crack open $|dz| = ?dx + ?dy$

Comment: Probably $|dy|$ is the arclength measure on $C$. It is commonly written as $ds(y)$ or $dS(y)$.

Comment: What exactly would that mean? I am aware that if $R(t) = r_x(t), r_y(t) ... $ parametrizes some path. Then the path integral $\int f(R(t)) dr$ would be $\int f(R(t)) R'(t) dt$ and if we instead consider $\int f(R(t)) \frac{R'(t)}{\sqrt{(r_x')^2 + (r_y')^2 ...}} dt$ then this integral is now arclength parametrized. I don't know how to fit the $|dy|$ notion into this

Comment: Actually thats a typo. Given $R$ to arclength parametrize the integral one wants to find $Q$ such that $(R_x'(Q(t)))^2 + (R_y'(Q(t)))^2 + ... = (Q'(t))^2$ and then $R(Q(t))$ is arclength parametrized i.e. $\int f(R(Q(t)) dr_Q = \int f(R(Q(t)) R'(Q)Q'$ is our parametrized integral

Comment: Cross posted for second half: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458991/what-is-known-about-the-analytic-continuation-of-mazyas-modified-harmonic-zeta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|dy|$ is the surface measure on $C$. In coordinates $y(t) = (a(t), b(t))$ parameterizing $C$, it is given by $|dy| = |y'(t)|\,dt = \sqrt{a'(t)^2 + b'(t)^2}\,dt$. So
$$\int_{C}f(y)|dy| = \int f(y(t))|y'(t)|\,dt.$$
For example, $\pi$ is defined as half the length of $C$:
$$\pi := \frac{1}{2}\int_{C}1|dy|.$$

Comment: Okay that clarifies the first half thank you so much! I think the second part can be a standalone question for mathoverflow